# How to remove duplicates from imported file?

Tags: excel

I have a macro that I use to import data on a daily basis.  If yesterday's import ended at row 100 then today's import will start at row 101.

Column B has unique values and I don't want any duplicates in my data.  How can I select only the imported file and remove duplicates in that file?

```
Sub Import_Data()
Dim Ret

Ret = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")

If Ret <> False Then
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;" & Ret, Destination:=Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select Input Cell", Type:=8))

    .Name = "Sample"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 437
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1)
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

    End With
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: use the `remove duplicates` feature against your new data by defining the specific range upon where to remove duplicates

Comment: How would I use that feature?  I don't know anything about VBA coding so I'm not sure how to use it.

Comment: Record a macro which highlights your range and then uses the remove duplicates button found under data tab and data tools  use the help within excel search for remove duplicates it will guide you further.  The real question is in the 2nd day's file, are you sure it's a duplicate and not just a "Replace prior with updated data?" in new row?  So should you be REMOVING a previous entry and keeping the most current only?  and do you have duplicates "across days" or only in a given file? and then how do you know which one to get rid of if  duplicate(s) are found? (Keep first? Last? Middle?)

Comment: Thank you I'll try that out to see if I can get it to work.

Comment: Within the file there should only be unique values in Column B.  If there is a duplicate value in that Column then the row should be deleted.  It doesn't matter what row is deleted as long as all the values in Column B are unique.  It should only search within the single day and should not across multiple days.

Comment: Then the duplicate is based on the day and column b. and can be added to the remove duplicates feature as such.